# Laravel 5.1: Laravelcollective 'Form' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravelcollective

I have installed laravelcollective/html as defined here: http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html.

Composer.json's require is:

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "shpasser/gae-support-l5": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
},
```

Ran composer update, which updated a lot of modules.

app.php's providers array includes:

```
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Shpasser\GaeSupportL5\GaeSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and in the aliases array I have:

```
    'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

I've tried running:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
```

and I've even tried deleting the vendor folder and reinstalling using

```
composer install
```

But still I'm getting the error:

```
WARNING: local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Form' not found'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You may need to add a backslash to find the `Form` facade, like this: `\Form`

Comment: @lowerends is that in the aliases array?

Comment: No. Do you have more info on where the error is thrown? Which file and line?

Comment: @lowerends  I've somewhat managed to fix my issue. I believe it was stemming from something messing up when I ran "composer update" and it was updating other components. So I'm starting with a fresh install of laravel, fully updated, and I'll copy my current classes and views in. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Good to know you solved it. You may want to answer to yourself and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've somewhat managed to fix my issue. I believe it was stemming from something messing up when I ran "composer update" and it was updating other components. So starting with a fresh install of laravel, fully updated, and copying the current classes and views in seems to have fixed it.